# How do I do a lua style table of functions in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-function

In lua, one can very easily create a table and add functions to it.

How do I do that in C#? My first idea was to use a List of delegates and fill the list with anonymous functions, but I can't get the syntax right.

```
public class PlanItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }   
    public List<BusinessRule> Rules;
}

public delegate bool BusinessRule(PlanItem item);

[Test]
public void TestIt()
{
    PlanItem item = new PlanItem();
    item.Rules.Add(
        BusinessRule(PlanItem item)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name);
        }
    );

   foreach(BusinessRule rule in item.Rules)
   {
     if(!rule(item))
         // write uh-oh
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
 item.Rules.Add((planItem) => 
 { 
     return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(planItem.Name); 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void TestIt()
{
    PlanItem item = new PlanItem();
    item.Rules.Add( (item) => {  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name); });
    item.Rules.ForEach( (rule) => { if(!rule(item) uhOh(item, outputStream);} );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# 2.0 without anonymous delegates:

```
BusinessRule rule = delegate(PlanItem planitem) {
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(planitem.Name);
};
item.Rules.Add(rule);
```